# $y = y'(2x) / y'(x)$: A seemingly difficult pantograph-type equation that yields an elementary function as a solution.

Tags: delay-differential-equations

Consider $y = \frac{y^{\prime}(2x)}{y'(x)}$.

I submit to you that $y = c e^{zx}$, where $c$ and $z$ are complex and $x$ real; is a solution to the equation. Working from the equation, how do you arrive at a solution? I chose $y = c e^{zx}$, and then derived this relationship between the function and the ratio between argument scaled derivatives.

Also, are there other types of solutions?

Edit: Turns out c has to be 1 and x can be maybe complex?

Comment: How does the true equation look like?

Comment: y = y'(2x) / y'(x), x real

Comment: Try MathJax for the equation!

Comment: I suck at MathJax, and I may have missed a factor of two.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @VadimChernetsov Thanks, that motivates me to reformulate the question.

Comment: $c$ must be $1$. $x$ does not need to be real.

Comment: If x was real then y=2 and the equation becomes $2=\frac 00$

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, I agree that my c has to be unity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $y=f(x)$ has a power series on some domain:

$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k $$

Then

$$ f'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k a_k x^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1) a_{k+1} x^k $$

$$ f'(2x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k a_k (2x)^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)2^k a_{k+1} x^k $$

$$ f(x) f'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{i=0}^{k} (i+1) a_{k-i} a_{i+1} \right) x^k $$

So $f'(2x) = f(x) f'(x)$ means that for every non-negative integer $k$,

$$ (k+1) 2^k a_{k+1} = \sum_{i=0}^k (i+1)a_{k-i} a_{i+1} $$
$$ (k+1) (2^k-a_0) a_{k+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (i+1) a_{k-i} a_{i+1} $$

So $a_{k+1}$ has a recurrence relation involving $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$. ($a_0$ does not appear on the right side.) If $a_1=0$, then by induction $a_k=0$ for every $k>0$. $f(x)=C$ is a trivial solution to $f'(2x)=f(x)f'(x)$, but not $f(x) = \frac{f'(2x)}{f'(x)}$. So $a_1 \neq 0$.

The recurrence equation with $k=0$ gives $(1-a_0)a_1=0$. Since $a_1 \neq 0$, $a_0=1$, and the recurrence equation becomes

$$ (k+1) (2^k-1) a_{k+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (i+1) a_{k-i} a_{i+1} $$

The first few values of $k$ give:

$$ 2 a_2 = a_1^2 $$
$$ 3 \cdot 3 a_3 = 3 a_1 a_2 $$
$$ 4 \cdot 7 a_4 = 4 a_1 a_3 + 2 a_2^2 $$
$$ 5 \cdot 15 a_5 = 5 a_1 a_4 + 5 a_2 a_3 $$

Then

$$ a_2 = \frac{1}{2} a_1^2; \quad  a_3 = \frac{1}{6} a_1^3;
 \quad a_4 = \frac{1}{24} a_1^4; \quad a_5 = \frac{1}{120} a_1^5 $$

The pattern is clear, $$a_k = \frac{a_1^k}{k!} $$

This can be proved by induction: If $k \geq 1$ and the formula holds for $a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$, then

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (i+1) a_{k-i} a_{i+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{i+1}{(k-i)!(i+1)!} a_1^{k+1} = \frac{a_1^{k+1}}{k!} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} {k \choose i} = (k+1) \frac{a_1^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} (2^k-1) $$

So the only smooth solutions with domain including $0$ are

$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(Cx)^k}{k!} = e^{Cx} $$

where $C = a_1$ is any complex value.

Comment: It's interesting, and kind of expected, that your constant c is 1. I think I was aiming too high with y = c e^(zx)

Comment: I think I have sobered up enough to accept this answer. So it's a Cauchy-type sum then? :)

Answer (score 3):

Multiply throughout by $2y’(x)$ to get the equivalent equation $2y(x)y’(x)= 2y’(2x)$. It can be seen that $2y(x)y’(x)$ is the derivative of $[y(x)]^2$ and $2y’(2x)$ is the derivative of $y(2x)$. It follows that these must differ by a constant, that is,

$$[y(x)]^2 = y(2x)+C\text{ for some }C\in\mathbb R$$

Any differentiable function $f:I\to\mathbb R$ ($I$ is an interval) having a nonzero derivative and satisfying this condition will be a solution to your differential equation. In particular, the family of functions $e^{zx}$ satisfy this condition with $C=0$.

**Edit**: we can improve this result slightly if we assume $0$ is in the domain of our solution $y$.

From the equation $2y(x)y’(x)=2y’(2x)$, it can be seen that $2y(0)y’(0)=2y’(0)$. We can’t have $y’(0)=0$ because the original differential equation requires that $y’$ be nonzero wherever it’s defined, so $2y(0)y’(0)=2y’(0)$ reduces to $y(0)=1$. Substituting $0$  for $x$ in $[y(x)]^2=y(2x)+C$ then implies $1^2=1+C$, so $C$ is necessarily $0$. Thus, $[y(x)]^2=y(2x)+C$ reduces to $[y(x)]^2=y(2x)$.

**Edit 2**: in fact, $0$ being in the domain is enough to force $y(x)=e^{cx}$ on some neighborhood of $0$. For simplicity, we will assume the domain of $y$ is $\mathbb R$.

From the identity $[y(x)]^2=y(2x)$ and induction, it can be seen that for any $n\in\mathbb N$,

$$[y(x)]^{2^n}=y\left(2^n x\right)\text{ for any }x\in\mathbb R$$

and consequently

\begin{align*}
y(x) &= y\left(2^n\cdot\frac{x}{2^n}\right)\\
&= \left[y\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)\right]^{2^n}\text{ for any }x\in\mathbb R\tag{$\ast$}
\end{align*}

We assumed that $y$ satisfies $y(x)=y'(2x)/y(x)$, so $y$ must be differentiable because this is the only way to make sense of a solution to this equation. It follows that $y$ is continuous everywhere, in particular at $0$. Since $y(0)=1>0$, continuity ensures $y(x)>0$ for every $x$ in some neighborhood $I$ of $0$. Thus, from $(\ast)$,

$$y\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=\left[y(x)\right]^{\frac{1}{2^n}}\text{ for every }x\in I$$

Since $y$ is differentiable, the chain rule applies and yields

$$\frac{1}{2^n}y'\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{2^n}\left[y(x)\right]^{\frac{1}{2^n}-1}y'(x)\text{ for every }x\in I$$

or

$$y'\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=\left[y(x)\right]^{\frac{1}{2^n}-1}y'(x)\text{ for every }x\in I\tag{$\dagger$}$$

Now, $y'$ is continuous everywhere because $y(x)=y'(2x)/y(x)$ implies $y'(x)=y(x/2)\cdot y(x/2)$ and $y(x/2)$ is continuous. It follows that $\lim_{x\to 0} y'(x)=y'(0)$ and consequently, for any fixed $x\in I$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}y'\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=y'(0)$$
$$\text{ and }$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[y(x)\right]^{\frac{1}{2^n}-1}y'(x)=\left[y(x)\right]^{0-1}y'(x)=\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}$$

Thus, as $n\to\infty$, equation $(\dagger)$ becomes $y'(0)=y'(x)/y(x)$. It immediately follows that $y(x)=e^{cx}$ for every $x\in I$ ($c:=y'(0)$), which is the desired result because $I$ is some neighborhood of $0$.

I'm not sure if this can be extended to the entire domain $\mathbb R$. Maybe the comments can help answer this.

Comment: Thanks! I will mull on this for some hours before accepting an answer.